# How to Define Combobox' Variables Without Recording Them Into Excel Sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have this report formatting tool development task and i want to add my userform some comboboxes. When i searched for how to use them on internet, i always saw them, they get their values from an excel sheet. My file already contains 2 sheets and i don't want it to have more. Is it possible to store combobox's values in the code?

http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html

Comment: Are saying, you want to populate combobox in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES IT'S POSSIBLE - if the answer to my comment is YES :)

Try the following code with what you require. Assume you have a VBA code, and you have a `combobox1`

```
With ComboBox1
   .AddItem "I am"
   .AddItem "Adding"
   .AddItem "Static"
   .AddItem "Values"
   .AddItem "From"
   .AddItem "VBA"
End With
```

Let us know if you need anything further. **Wish you could update yours question with anything you have trying so far.**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, that was what i have in my mind. :) :)

*ps: what i tried was the same thing on the link. Then i tried to remove getting values from sheet and initialize them to strings in code but couldn't do that. I didn't post my previous effort at least for this because it was all basic and i knew this question would have one simple solution

Comment: I am glad it helped :) and BTW, you can save all the static values in one hidden sheet in the file. Pull them into an array, then push the array elements into the combobox using a loop. Saves lines of code though. If you can let us know any further requirements for your design, happy to pitch some ideas :)

Comment: Actually it's a good hint for large set of options on comboboxes. But mine has only 5 values [1,5] . But i'll keep it in mind for future tasks